# Windows 8.1 - WiFi connection troubles

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, thinkpad

I recently got a Thinkpad Edge E430 for work, with Win 8.1 installed. My problem is that I can't connect to any Wireless connection.
Whenever I want to connect to WiFi, Windows tries to connect for a while and then a "Windows can't connect to network" message appears.
As I said I'm running Win 8.1 on a ThinkPad Edge E430, and the wifi adapter is "Wireless LAN PCI Express Half Mini Card Adapter".

The weird thing is sometimes it can connect, but most times it just can't. I have good signal and I tried in multiple connections.
I'd like an answer that doesn't include modem's configuration because the problem is clearly with the laptop and also I can't configure the modem (because is from office).

**Things I tried and didn't worked:**

- I got the latest drivers from Lenovo's website and installed them.
- Updated BIOS
- Installed drivers that comes with Windows 8.1
- Disabled all adapters

Comment: Test it with another WiFi network to see if it behaves the same way.  Open up the back of the notebook and ensure the WiFi antennas are properly attached to the WiFi adapter.

Comment: By showing the name of the access point and the signal strength, the wifi adapter is good at receiving signals. There may be problems in sending signals as you could not login.

Answer (score 0):

Check it if your ThinkPad came with the Intel AN7260. Lenovo (and many others brands) are using this particulary card. Check the driver´s versions of your card and go to the ThinkPads Support area on the Lenovo´s web-site. You probably have to update your drive.